# Could the figure created in python can appear all the time in notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I tried to make interactive in python by using Plotly in Jupyter Notebook.

This is the import code.

`import plotly.graph_objects as go`

Although I can make the figure successfully. Since I used the server, I do not need to close the jupyter notebook. However, the next time I open the notebook, the image will disappear automatically. I have to restart the Jupiter notebook again and make the figure again.

Who knows how to make the figure appears all the time?

Comment: If you have access to a filesystem (that won’t get wiped when you shutdown jupyter) you can save the image to a file and render it in a markdown cell.

Answer (score 0):

In general, plotly graphs will get cached by Jupyter notebook, in your case it could be due to an access issue to file system of the server. On the other hand, Jupyter provides a way to export the notebook as `HTML` format.

The option is available in `File->download as -> HTML`

Comment: Thanks, it works by exporting HTML. But how can I get cached by using Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Basically there is no feature like caching in Jupyter notebook. The Jupyter notebook core is built with ZeroMQ, which receives the code snippet as a message and executes in a separate thread and returns back to the frontend. The only way to persist the output is by the export them into a file format.